# Do you have some hints as to how to solve the following problem?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots,A_n,\ldots$ be a collection of subsets in $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ and let $$A=A_1\times A_2\times A_3\times\ldots\subseteq[0,1]^{\Bbb N}\;.$$ Show that

$$\operatorname{Cl}A=\operatorname{Cl}A_1\times\operatorname{Cl}A_2\times\operatorname{Cl}A_3\times\ldots\times\operatorname{Cl}A_n\times\ldots$$

for any topology $t$ on $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ such that $t_T\subseteq t\subseteq t_B$, where $t_T$ is the usual product topology, and $t_B$ is the box topology.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Jose, please check to make sure that I correctly interpreted everything. Also, do you really want the sets $A_n$ to be subsets of $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$, or should they be subsets of $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Yiorgios: While I think it very likely that the sets $A_n$ are supposed to be subsets of $[0,1]$, I’m not willing to change it without the OP’s consent.

Comment: @Brian: The product of subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ is not a subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: @Yiorgios: Obviously. That does not justify making a substantive change to the OP’s question without his consent. Moreover, it **is** a subset of $([0,1]^{\Bbb N})^{\Bbb N}$, which can be identified naturally with $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$, and while I very much doubt that this is what’s intended, it **is** possible.

Answer (score 1):

As the standard product topology (or weak topology) is weaker than the box topology, and hence the box topology has more closed sets, we have that 
$$
\mathrm{Cl}_{B}(A) \subset \mathrm{Cl}_{T}(A). 
$$
Note also that $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathrm{Cl}\, A_n$ is closed in both topologies, as an intersection of closed sets, and hence
$$
\mathrm{Cl}_{B}(A) \subset \mathrm{Cl}_{T}(A) \subset \prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathrm{Cl}\, A_n.
$$

Therefore, it suffices to show that 
$$
\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathrm{Cl}\, A_n\subset\mathrm{Cl}_{B}(A).
$$
This is no harder than proving that
$$
\mathrm{Cl}\,A_1\times\mathrm{Cl}\,A_2\subset \mathrm{Cl}\,(A_1\times A_2).
$$

Comment: @Brian: Thanks. See edited version.